# Javascript file not loading from layout in view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-grid

I am trying to load a kendo grid, which I have a method in my `jQuery` file to initialize it, but my problem is that for some reason my `grid.js` file is not being loaded onto the page.

Layout file referencing the `grid.js` file:

```
<script defer src="~/js/grid.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
}
```

My view referencing the layout file:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutList.cshtml";
}
```

When I inspect for the script in sources using dev tools it is nowhere to be found, but other .js files referenced other places are being loaded.

**UPDATE**
My `_LayoutList.cshtml` gets its layout from `_Layout.cshtml`. I tested moving the `<script>` tag to `_Layout.cshtml` and the `grid.js` file was finally in my sources. I obviously can't have every page that is loaded have the `grid.js` file, so I still need to figure out why `_LayoutList.cshtml` isn't using `grid.js`

**EDIT:**
I tried removing `defer` from my `<script>` tag, to make it
`<script src="~/js/grid.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`
Unfortunately, that did not fix it.

I also checked the console for errors, but didn't find any.

**EDIT:**
I tried opening the window in incognito mode to avoid the cached version of the page. Did not fix my issue.

Comment: Try removing `defer`. Depending on how your page is structured that may cause more problems than it solves. Failing that, check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, just tested that, didn't fix my issue unfortunately. Checked console for errors, none exist.

Comment: in devtools can you checkout the network tab and see what is happening to the request being made for `grid.js` file

Comment: @rbansal For scripts in the network tab, I see other scripts I have called to on the page, but not the `grid.js` file.

Comment: do you mean there is no call to fetch the file in network?

Comment: @rbansal Correct. Clarified my response.

Comment: i am just guessing here but maybe the `asp-append-version` tag is causing this... that tag causes the file's initial version to be cached.
Try opening the page in **incognito mode**

Comment: @rbansal Tested in incognito, and I also hard refreshed and cleared cache in the normal window but that didn't work.

Comment: So,do you  have problems when you create a new js file and load it?Does the js file in right path?Do you add it in your `_LayoutList.cshtml` instead of the dafault `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: @XingZou Yes, the file is in the correct place. Yes, It is in my `_LayoutList.cshtml` file. `_LayoutList.cshtml` gets its own layout from the default `_Layout.cshtml` though

Comment: Updated origninal post

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
}
```

You are declaring a section called "Scripts" that renders another section Called Scripts...

You don't need to call `@RenderSection` You do that on the layout page. Just write:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/grid.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

You might want to remove the `asp-append-version` tag and just call the exact file name you have since it might be calling the script by a name that it is not correct.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. Rendering the Scripts section allows the other scripts I have on the page to work on the end user side of things. Also, as I stated in my post. I have already attempted to remove the `asp-append-version` tag, but that did not work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `~/` and let just `js/grid.js`?

Comment: Yes, I have. Did not fix my issue.

Comment: Just one comment. The `@RenderScript` directive should be called only by the layout page and you should specify the `@Section Scripts` in the rest of the pages that have that Layout. I know that your issue is not resolved but the way you have the `@section Scripts` is incorrect. Are you using `System.Web.Optimization` ?

Comment: I do have the `@RenderScript` tag in the layout. Where would I be using `System.Web.Optimization`?

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: That is what I am trying to say. That the `@RenderSection` should be *only* in the layout and in the *page* should be just `@section Scripts {` and your `<script>` tags. You would be using the `System.Web.Optimization` in the layouts or `ViewImports.?html` or any other view with the `@using` directive at the top of the page.

Comment: Gotcha. When I tried to add the using tag it couldn't find `System.Web.Optimization`

Comment: You need to import the assembly or install it via Nuget. Your issue anyways seems to me that the two layouts are probably calling two `@RenderSection` with the same name

Comment: Would `System.Web.Optimiization` conflict with webpack? What's the point of installing it? Also if you put a scripts section on a child page, the layoutlist puts that in a certain spot and then anything layoutlist puts into the scripts section gets put into the layout where it renders the section, correct?

Comment: Ok. You don't need to install it. You are using webpack. At this point, I am not sure what you have. I would need to see the project to help you further. At the end of the day, you only have ONE page. Sections names in the layouts should be unique. So instead of calling it `Scripts` you can call ut `ListScripts` or something like that. My personal preference is to have just one page layout without nesting to avoid any kind of issues but nesting layouts should work.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it.